# confused with sizeof derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, sizeof

```
class base
{
  private:
  int a;
  };
class base2
{
  private:
  int b;
  };
class derived:public base,public base2
{
  private:
  int c;
  };
main()
{
  base b;
  derived d;
  cout<<size of(base)<<size of(base2)<<size of(derived);
}
```

since int a and int b are private variables.so they are not getting inherited in derived class.so the output should be 4 4 4 but it is
output:4 4 12
why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> since `int a` and `int b` are private variables.so they are not getting inherited in `derived` class

That's wrong - of course they are getting inherited, the code in the base class wouldn't be able to work without them. It's just that `derived` cannot get to them, but it does not change the `sizeof` the derived class.

Consider this extension of your example:

```
class base {
private:
    int a;
protected:
    base() : a(123) {}
    void showA() {cout << a << endl;}
};

class base2 {
private:
    int b;
protected:
    base2() : b(321) {}
    void showB() {cout << b << endl;}
};

class derived:public base,public base2 {
private:
    int c;
public:
    derived() : c (987) {}
    void show() {
        showA();
        showB();
        cout << c << endl;
    }
};
```

Even though your `derived` class cannot read or change `a` and `b`, it can show their values by calling the corresponding functions in its bases. Therefore, the variables must remain there, otherwise the `showA` and `showB` member functions wouldn't be able to do their work.

Comment: i have read that its only protected and public member that get inherited but not the private members

Comment: @desprado Then you read wrong. Everything is inherited, public/protected/private is about *access* not about *inheritance*

Comment: if it is like this then why one cannot use private members of base class in derived class

Comment: @desprado Because you don't have *access*, that doesn't mean the members aren't there. They are there but you cannot access them.

Comment: @john does it mean that constructor also gets inherited?

Comment: @desprado Constructors and other functions get inherited only in the sense that if the derived class makes use of them, directly or through other functions or constructors to which the derived class has access, these functions would be there. They do not become available to the users of your derived class. In addition, inherited constructors in the bases cannot be used by users outside of the derived class to construct instances of the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

`private:` or `protected:` or `public:` annotations on member fields affect only visibility. But the fields are still in the classes.

Take several days to read a good C++ programming book.